# Do not render component for routes that have /:id

Tags: reactjs, react-router

**GOAL**: Render Navigation component on all routes other than `/search` and all `/:id` (eg., username routes)

Here is my code that conditionally renders the `Navigation` component based on its width:

```js
let { pathname } = useLocation();
  const isTallEnough = useMedia("(min-width: 1000px)");
  if (!user.uid && pathname == "/" && !isTallEnough) return null;
  if (!user.uid && pathname === "/search" && !isTallEnough) return null;
```

How can I ensure that when on a `/:id` route that the navigation component won't render?

Comment: You aren't using react-router-dom or any lib that handles the routing right? You're doing it all by yourself with custom implementation? I found out by reading your previous question that you're using react-render-dom, you better be accurate to get an accurate answer mate!

Comment: You should probably take a look at this: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useroutematch. It looks like what you need, although you could have to rethink a bit your router configuration/setup.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you use React Router, you can use [`useRouteMatch`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useroutematch) hook. This way you can set something like this:

```js
// outside of component
function useShouldRenderComponent() {
  let is_search = useRouteMatch('/search');
  let is_user_id = useRouteMatch('/user/:id');
  let is_wide_enough = useMedia("(min-width: 1000px)")
  // add more, if needed

  return !(is_search || is_user_id) && is_wide_enough;
}

// in component

let shouldRenderComponent = useShouldRenderComponent();

if (!shouldRenderComponent) return null;
return <Navigation/>
```